# Discord.js client.on(Events.InteractionCreate) blocks after 2 commands instead of queueing them all

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord, discord.js

Why does Discord.js client.on(Events.InteractionCreate) blocks after 2 commands instead of queueing them all even though, I am using all async functions and awaiting the execution of the command every time? How do I make it so that it handles the next one as soon as the previous one is awaiting?
The commands I'm running are async and needs to wait for io tasks to finish anyways so it makes sense to batch them instead of only doing 2 at a time.

I've tried everything from making all the functions asynchronous and awaiting when necessary... still does not work

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction: any) => {
console.log("new interaction");
if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

if (!command) {
  console.error(
    `No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`
  );
  return;
}

try {
  // await command.execute(interaction, { addToQueue });
  await command.execute(interaction);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);

  try {
    await interaction.reply({
      content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {}
}
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.